# TwitterOAuth Implementation Error Code 215: Bad Authentication Data

Tags: php, authentication, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm receiving a TwitterOAuthException when trying to implement a request_token & replicating the functionality of [TwitterOAuth](https://twitteroauth.com/redirect.php).

The error

The code I am using is as follows:

```
require_once $cfg['server']['root']."/inc/lib/tw/autoload.php";

use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

define('CONSUMER_KEY', getenv('SlUlxP1lmXqqCCqoUOy0DGAL6'));
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', getenv('MM0vL2aRwp9rgS7qUF8UNEO3NtYv9W7QCZYSDzAyrZt7qa0XGg'));
define('OAUTH_CALLBACK', getenv('http://www.example-site.com/login/'));

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
pA($connection); //print connection contents

$request_token = $connection->oauth('oauth/request_token', array('oauth_callback' => OAUTH_CALLBACK));

pA($request_token); //print connection contentsa
```

The output I get is:

```
Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth Object
(
    [response:Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth:private] => Abraham\TwitterOAuth\Response Object
        (
            [apiPath:Abraham\TwitterOAuth\Response:private] => 
            [httpCode:Abraham\TwitterOAuth\Response:private] => 0
            [headers:Abraham\TwitterOAuth\Response:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [body:Abraham\TwitterOAuth\Response:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [xHeaders:Abraham\TwitterOAuth\Response:private] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [bearer:Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth:private] => 
    [consumer:Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth:private] => Abraham\TwitterOAuth\Consumer Object
        (
            [key] => 
            [secret] => 
            [callbackUrl] => 
        )

    [token:Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth:private] => 
    [signatureMethod:Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth:private] => Abraham\TwitterOAuth\HmacSha1 Object
        (
        )

    [timeout:protected] => 5
    [connectionTimeout:protected] => 5
    [decodeJsonAsArray:protected] => 
    [userAgent:protected] => TwitterOAuth (+https://twitteroauth.com)
    [proxy:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuthException' with message '{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}' in /home/user/public/test.com/public/inc/lib/tw/src/TwitterOAuth.php:137 Stack trace: #0 /home/chrismoore/public/trybe-ing.com/public/login/tw/tw_header.php(13): Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth->oauth('oauth/request_t...', Array) #1 /home/user/public/test.com/public/login/index.php(6): require_once('/home/user...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/user/public/test.com/public/inc/lib/tw/src/TwitterOAuth.php on line 137
```

Can anyone help me find a solution to this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getenv()` looks for an environment variable with the name passed as a string argument. But it looks like you've passed the values you intend to use to `getenv()`.  (by the way, if this is true, probably best not to put your secret in plaintext on a public website?)

Have you tried just passing those strings as the second argument to `define()`, without wrapping in `getenv()`?

Comment: No. I'll try that now. Thanks